# Java Calculator "equal" button not working

Tags: java, error-handling, exception, calculator, formatter

So I am working on calculator in Java and everything seems to be working except for when I actually click the equal sign. I get an error that I've never seen before and I'm not sure what it means.

I'm not sure how much code I should post here, but since the only highlights/warning are contained within equal button action event I will post that code first.

```
 private void btnEqualsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        secondNum = Double.parseDouble(calcField.getText());
        if (operation == "+") {
            result = firstNum + secondNum;
            answer = String.format("%.of", result);
            calcField.setText(answer);
        } else  if (operation == "-") {
            result = firstNum - secondNum;
            answer = String.format("%.of", result);
            calcField.setText(answer);  
        } else if (operation == "*") {
            result = firstNum * secondNum;
            answer = String.format("%.of", result);
            calcField.setText(answer);  
        } else if(operation == "/") {
            result = firstNum / secondNum;
            answer = String.format("%.of", result);
            calcField.setText(answer);  
        }
    }
```

This is a picture of my screen:

https://i.gyazo.com/8b15ec8b1c7ec7982122230075b8370a.png

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at online.billing.system.BillingGUI.btnEqualsActionPerformed(BillingGUI.java:351)
    at online.billing.system.BillingGUI.access$1600(BillingGUI.java:8)
    at online.billing.system.BillingGUI$17.actionPerformed(BillingGUI.java:172)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at online.billing.system.BillingGUI.btnEqualsActionPerformed(BillingGUI.java:351)
    at online.billing.system.BillingGUI.access$1600(BillingGUI.java:8)
    at online.billing.system.BillingGUI$17.actionPerformed(BillingGUI.java:172)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

I would be very appreciative if anybody would be willing to offer me some insight as to what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for reading over my thread.

Comment: I guess either firstNum or secondNum is empty when you calculate the result. try just printing them out in the console when the event triggers

Comment: don't use operation == "*".  use "*".equals(operation). Or in your case, you can use switch for string if your Java is 7 or higher

Comment: Don't use == to compare Strings in Java, use equals instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume exception is getting thrown from this line:

```
secondNum = Double.parseDouble(calcField.getText());
```

And the exception is :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
```

And this exception says that for parsing, an empty String has been passed. 
Ensure that calcField.Text is not empty.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I added                                                                     System.out.print(calcField.getText()); to the function and it returned the last digit I entered so I'm assuming that calcField does in fact have a value. Thank you though.. I'm just going to keep working away at this.

Comment: @CarsonClark do you mind posting more code? for example : where is your calcField defined and is it referenced else where?

Comment: Hello, calcField was just the name of my jTextField and it was declared automatically along with the rest of my objects as I used a JFrameForm in Netbeans. They were declared under the main method here: https://i.gyazo.com/a5889ba2dce3d2d3da979c0c0bb00840.png                       I have solved my issue by just removing the "string.format" and converting my Double "result" variable into a String via the String.valueOf method. It's not an ideal resolution but I'll come back to it later once I add the rest of the features I want to add. Thanks for your help and everyone else's.

Answer (score -1):

Basically it's saying that you have an empty string when trying to parse to double so you should do this check before:

```
if(calcField.getText() != null && !calcField.getText().isEmpty())
```

Your code will look something like this (not tried myself):

```
private void btnEqualsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    if(calcField.getText() != null && !calcField.getText().isEmpty()) {
        secondNum = Double.parseDouble(calcField.getText());
        if (operation == "+") {
            result = firstNum + secondNum;
            answer = String.format("%.of", result);
            calcField.setText(answer);
        } else  if (operation == "-") {
            result = firstNum - secondNum;
            answer = String.format("%.of", result);
            calcField.setText(answer);  
        } else if (operation == "*") {
            result = firstNum * secondNum;
            answer = String.format("%.of", result);
            calcField.setText(answer);  
        } else if(operation == "/") {
            result = firstNum / secondNum;
            answer = String.format("%.of", result);
            calcField.setText(answer);  
        }
    }          
}
```